# Configure adapter setting to add loopback IP address to the list of DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have Active Directory integrated DNS.  I ran the Best Practices Analyzer (BPA) for DNS and received the following error:

[image: Pic1]

I have the following network adapters:

[image: Pic2]

I am not using the second Ethernet adapter.  Here is what I have for the other one:

[image: Pic3]

[image: Pic4]

As you can see I have the loopback address for IPv4 (127.0.0.1) and the loopback address for IPv6 (::1).

Why am I seeing this error when I run the BPA for the DNS role?  Is there something else I need to do to correct this?

Comment: If you do not use IPv6, have you thought about disabling it? If not, have you tried doing as the error message indicates and putting the IPv6 of another name server first rather than `::1` ?

Comment: **@gparent** I didn't even think about disabling IPv6.  Easy fix.

Comment: I'm no expert on AD, so I'd look into the potential side effects, but glad it helped you out.

Comment: @gparent, actually I take it back.  It didn't work.  I ran BPA again once I disabled IPv6 and it still show the error.

Comment: Welp. Not sure what to say then, sorry.